# c++ passing a value to a char array through arguments

Tags: c++, arrays

```
class Link{       
   char name[];
   Link *next;
};

Link::Link(char pname[]){       
   next=NULL;
   name[]=pname;    
};
```

How can I assign value I am passing (`pname`) when creating object to `name[]` in the class `Link`?

Comment: Use `std::string` and your life will be a lot easier.

Comment: Do you wish to copy the _reference_ to the underlying chars, or the chars themselves? You can remove a lot of stress and ambiguity here by using `std::string`, `std::array<char, n>` or `std::vector<char>` depending on what you intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you would use `std::string` to store strings:

```
class Link{       
   std::string name;
   Link *next;
};

Link::Link(char const pname[]) : next(NULL), name(pname) {}
```

If you have a very good reason for embedding an array of characters rather than letting the standard string class take care of memory allocation for you, then you would need something like:

```
class Link{       
   char name[I_HOPE_THIS_IS_BIG_ENOUGH];
   Link *next;
};

Link::Link(char const pname[]) : next(NULL) {
    name[sizeof name - 1] = 0;
    std::strncpy(name, pname, sizeof name);
    if (name[sizeof name - 1] != 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Whoops! My buffer was too small.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you cannot have a `char name[]` as a member of a class. The type has to be complete, i.e. a strict fixed array size has to be specified explicitly

```
class Link {       
   char name[100];
   Link *next;
};
```

Secondly, raw arrays cannot be assigned or copy-initialized. To copy data from one generic array to the other you can use a library function

```
Link::Link(const char pname[]) : next(NULL) {       
   std::copy(pname, pname + 100, name);
   // Assuming `pname` also points to an array of 100 chars
}
```

or, if we are dealing with a zero-terminated character array (aka C-string)

```
Link::Link(const char pname[]) : next(NULL) {       
   assert(std::strlen(pname) < 100);
   std::strcpy(name, pname);
}
```

Thirdly, and most importantly, in many cases the proper solution will depend on the nature of your array. What is `name` in your case? You provided no information in your question. Is it a string or not? If it is supposed to be a string, you might be much better off using `std::string` class instead of the raw char array. Even if you need an array (not a string), you might be better off using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution:

```
class Link {
Link(char* pname )  {
     name=pname;
}
char* name;
Link *next;
};
```

Comment: And what happens when the data pointed to is destroyed (`{char name[] = "abc"; Link l(name);}`)?

Comment: You'll need to document the requirement that the string must outlive the `Link` object; and hope that the users obey that requirement, since there's no way to enforce it.